# Makefile: read input variable and set several variables

Tags: makefile

I have a makefile where I want to read file name from input and then make other names based on it`s name. I have tried the following code

```
mlext = .ml
testext = test.ml
nativeext = test.native

test: 
    @read -p "Enter file name: " file; \
    echo $$file$(mlext); \
    echo $$file$(testext); \
    echo $$file$(nativeext)
```

for example:

If i type: foo

then I want to get `foo.ml`, `footest.ml`, `footest.native`

however, I can only get `foo.ml`. For the rest two i only get `.ml` and `.native`

How can i fix this?

Comment: This kind of interactive processing really isn't make's domain, is there any reason you can't accept a variable on input, e.g. `make file=foo`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, let us see what is the exact recipe given to the shell by removing the `@` in your Makefile:

```
read -p "Enter file name: " file; \
echo $file.ml; \
echo $filetest.ml; \
echo $filetest.native;
```

The issue is thus that the content of `$(testext)` gets appended to `$$file`, creating the shell variable `$filetest`, which (very probably) does not exist, resulting in an empty string in the end. This does not occur with `$(mlext)`, as the initial dot cannot be part of a variable name.

To overcome this, use `$${file}` instead of `$$file` in your Makefile rule.